# du: Follow symlinks if symlink points to outside directories, don't follow otherwise

Tags: bash, perl

I wonder whether there's some rather simple shell incantation to calculate the disk usage of a directory (using the `du` command) but with the following requirements: symlinks that point to files/subdirectories inside the directory should not be followed, but symlinks to outside files/subdirectories should. Or whether I need to do some scripting to accomplish this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless I have missed something in your question, `du` already does that when instructed to follow symlinks (`-L`).

I got two trees:

`tree1/`:

```
├── dir1
│   └── file
├── dirA -> ../tree2/dirA
└── link1 -> dir1
```

and `tree2/`:

```
.
└── dirA
    └── file
```

File is in both cases 1MB in size.

Now run `du -shL` on `tree1/`:

```
$ du -shL tree1
2.0M    tree1
```

While file can be seen three times in `tree1/` when following symlinks:

```
$ find tree1 -follow -type f
tree1/dirA/file
tree1/link1/file
tree1/dir1/file
```

It only counted twice towards the total. Namely once from `tree1/` and once linked in from `tree2/dirA/` (or what I understood as you meaning from outside / not being sub-directories of `tree1/`).

It would also seem to make sense, because being links inside the same tree, they do not really consume additional disk space (beyond the symlink entry).

---

I've also grown the `tree1` a bit to:

```
.
├── dir1
│   └── file
├── dir2
│   └── file -> ../dir1/file
├── dirA -> ../tree2/dirA
└── link1 -> dir1
```

And ran:

```
$ du -abcL .
1048576 ./dir2/file
1048636 ./dir2
1048576 ./dirA/file
1048636 ./dirA
60      ./link1
2097452 .
2097452 total
```

As you can see, links only count towards total / size of `.` with size of link entry (even though I admit `60` confuses me a but, I'd expect `4`) and not (dereferenced) content of the file they point to.

Is this what you wanted or close enough?

Comment: Of course, you're right! A simple -L would accomplish what I want.